# Как добавить контакт в телеграм канал Python

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Не удаётся добавить контакт в канал.
Копался в документации телеги, не совсем понимаю какой путь у InviteToChannel.
Буду очень рад, если подскажете!
Ниже часть кода:

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.types import InputPhoneContact
from pyrogram.raw.functions.channels import InviteToChannel

api_id = x
api_hash = "x"

app = Client("volt", api_id, api_hash)

with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    numbers = f.read().split("\n")

async def step_1():
    async with app:
        for number in numbers:
            try:
                await app.import_contacts([InputPhoneContact(number, "Client")])
            except:
                continue

async def step_2():
    async with app:
        for number in numbers:
            await app.invoke(InviteToChannel(channel="-1001664379827", users=number))

async def step_3():
    async with app:
        for number in numbers:
            try:
                await app.delete_contacts(number)
            except:
                continue

def main():
    app.run(step_1())
    app.run(step_2())
    app.run(step_3())

main()
```

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: Ну вы не так используете функцию, судя по документации. Пример: `update = client.send(
  functions.channels.InviteToChannel(
   channel=client.resolve_peer(destination),
   users=ids
  )
 )`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: @ClarkDevlin не получается, а можете прислать линк на документацию?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send'
на данный момент

Comment: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyrogram/stable/pyrogram.pdf 136 страница

Comment: @ClarkDevlin благодарю за документацию)
Изначально отбилось это -  `No module named 'pyrogram.api`
я подкорректировал и стало - `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Я так понимаю нужен delay в виде `await asyncio.sleep(delay)`

Comment: нет, вы вызываете какую-то функцию синхронно, а она асинхронная, покажите код, обновив вопрос

Comment: @ClarkDevlin обновил запрос, вставил код полностью, заранее спасибо!

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Вопрос не актуален, думал с помощью этого способа можно будет обойти `pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PeerIdInvalid: Telegram says: [400 PEER_ID_INVALID] - The peer id being used is invalid or not known yet. Make sure you meet the peer before interacting with it`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @ClarkDevlin А сможете подсказать, какое взаимодействие необходимо сделать с номером телефона, чтобы я мог добавить его в канал и избежать ошибку из комментария выше?

Comment: Никак, иначе можно было бы спарсить всех людей в телеграме

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Понятно. Спасибо огромное)